# Requesting help to understand Javascript variable scope

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

I am afraid many people are going to find my question quite trivial, but I need to ask it.

(As requested by a lot of people, I have edited the code so that you can reproduce it.)

I have a JavaScript global variable defined within a script tag, as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<!--JQUERY-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_test/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var store_categories = []; 
    function init_filtering() {
        store_categories.push('data');
        alert ("alert1: "+ store_categories);
    }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">$( init_filtering );</script>

</head>  
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert ("alert2: "+ store_categories);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the page is loaded, alert2 appears first with blank value and then alert1 appears showing 'data' as value.

Can anyone please tell me what is happening?

Comment: Try `window.store_categories = [];`

Comment: You don't have any values in that array. Where (when) do you add them? [Worksforme](http://jsbin.com/utulaf/1/), btw - show us your whole code or at least a demo that reproduces the issue

Comment: What is happening in-between?

Comment: Hi asprin; thanks for your reply...will you please elaborate a little :-)

Comment: Yes if i assing a hard code in value to that array it shows the same value in both the alerts. Also mention the code where you are assigning the values to that array. will help everyone

Comment: Bergi, Aman: I have added some code to show where data is being inserted in the array - its happening in the first block. Esailija: Nothing happens to the array variable in between.

Comment: Your code, as show (removing the ellipsis to prevent syntax errors), works as expected. It produces two alerts, both saying "data". Produce a minimal example that doesn't work as you want it and the reason will probably be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(function() {...})` executes equivalent to `$.ready()`  whereas your inline script will execute as soon as it is parsed in the document.

This means that the function you specify is deferred until the page loads.

An empty array toString is an empty string which is why you see nothing in your first `alert`.

Answer (score 2):

`alert ("alert2: "+ store_categories);` runs immediately.

`$( init_filtering );` is an unhelpful (see [self-documenting code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting)) shortcut to make `init_filtering` run when the DOM is ready (i.e. after `</html>` has parsed).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Quentin. To provide some additional information, in my actual code, `alert2` is in a condition:`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` but still alert2 is showing blank.So, can you please suggest a solution so that alert2 can show the value of the `store_categories` variable?

Comment: @ShahriarNKhondokar — Do the same thing you do to the init_filtering function. Delay calling it until after init_filtering has run.